# Trouble reading data from USB device using Python

Tags: python, usb, libusb, pyusb

I am using PyUSB library to read data from my USB mouse in windows. I was able to run the code in a UBUNTU virtual machine, but I can't replicate the same in windows. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Following is the code and the error it throws :

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

# decimal vendor and product values
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=1133, idProduct=49278)
if dev is None :
    raise ValueError('Device is not found')

print(dev)

# first endpoint
interface = 0
endpoint = dev[0][(0,0)][0]
# if the OS kernel already claimed the device, which is most likely true

if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(interface) is True:
  # tell the kernel to detach
  dev.detach_kernel_driver(interface)
  # claim the device
  usb.util.claim_interface(dev, interface)
collected = 0
attempts = 50
while collected < attempts :
    try:
        data = dev.read(endpoint.bEndpointAddress,endpoint.wMaxPacketSize)
        collected += 1
        print(data)
    except usb.core.USBError as e:
        data = None
        if e.args == ('Operation timed out',):
            continue
# release the device
usb.util.release_interface(dev, interface)
# reattach the device to the OS kernel
dev.attach_kernel_driver(interface)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\BCD\i360\python\usb_reader.py", line 27, in <module>
    if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(interface) is True:
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 1107, in is_kernel_driver_active
    self._ctx.managed_open()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 131, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 804, in open_device
    return _DeviceHandle(dev)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 652, in __init__
    _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 600, in _check
    raise NotImplementedError(_strerror(ret))
NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform
```

Comment: Handle the exception!

Answer (score 0):

The error says exactly what's wrong: You're using a function that makes no sense on your operating system (Windows).

So, don't do that? Either, if you know this is something only running on Windows, remove the check, or better, `try:`-handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`dev.is_kernel_driver_active(interface)` is not supported in Windows

Comment: Can you suggest something that is supported in Windows. This is my first time working with PyUSB. WOuld really appreciate if you could help me with it